# VBulletin: Search inside BBCode

Tags: search, bbcode, vbulletin

Goal: In vB search results, to include posts that "quotes" the user when that user name is search keyword.

In a post body, it looks like [QUOTE="username"] and vB seems not searching inside the BB code.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When vBulletin does a search by username, it ends up doing a database query like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM post WHERE username = 'username'
```

Find that query (it's in search.php) and change it to something like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM post WHERE username = 'username' OR pagetext LIKE '%[QUOTE=username%'
```

You'll probably need a bunch of tweaks and testing to get it right, but that should get you closer to a solution.

**N.B. Be sure to sanitize the username. Usernames are not safe to insert into SQL directly!**